# Proper exit the Pebble app_event_loop function

Tags: c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I am developing an application for the Pebble smartwatch. An essential part of a Pebble C application is the app_event_loop() function. I was wondering whats the correct way to exit this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly exit the loop - this will happen automatically when the user presses the back button when on the top-level window.

If you wish to do so programatically then you can invoke [`window_stack_pop_all`](https://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/User_Interface/Window_Stack/#window_stack_pop_all) to pop all the windows off the stack and thus exit your app.